# Javascript regular expression to capture characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have written the following regexp in Javascript:

```
var rule = /^<[a-zA-Z0-9].*>/;
```

And the I checked it against this string:

```
var str = "<string stringValue><string2 stringValue>";
```

And the I executed:

```
var res = rule.exec(str);
```

And the res retruns:

```
<string stringValue> <string2 stringValue2>
```

Everything works in the way I need. But I must change two things:
1- First capture each occurrence (i mean each block of tag, in my example there are two)

2- I should strip off the tags [<>] in returned value. Is it then possible?

Comment: you can use secondary functions to remove the "<" and ">"

Comment: no I want to see if it is possible with RegExp or not

Comment: I don't quite understand point 1... you mean you want to get the whole "string stringValue" content of a tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular expressions are, by default, "greedy". The `.*` in your rule will match as many characters as possible while still succeeding. Also, since you used `^` at the start, your pattern would only match the tag at the start of your input. This is why you are matching too much currently.

```
/<([^>]*)>/
```

Will match either tag, and put the contents (without the < >) in a capture group.

To find every tag, you can run the regular expression multiple times. Adding `/g` to the end makes the expression global, which allows for this behaviour.

```
var rule = /<([^>]*)>/g,
    match,
    tags = [],
    input = "<string stringValue><string2 stringValue>";

while (match = rule.exec(input)) {
    tags.push(match[1]);
}

console.log(tags);
```

In each loop, `match[1]` refers to the first capture group, the parentheses in the expression.

It will return:

```
[ "string stringValue", "string2 stringValue" ]
```

Answer (score 4):

I guess you want to get the key value pair.
Try the code below:

```
var rule = /<([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\s+([a-zA-Z0-9]*)>/g;
var str = "<string stringValue><string2 stringValue>";
var res;

while((res = rule.exec(str)) !== null) {
    console.log("key: "+res[1]+" value: "+res[2]);
}

//output
//key: string value: stringValue
//key: string2 value: stringValue
```

Comment: so res is an array with the regex groups in it?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
var reg = /<[a-zA-Z0-9][^>]*>/g;
var str = "<string stringValue><string2 stringValue>";
var res = str.match(reg);
res = res ? res.map(function(i){return i.replace(/^<|>$/g, '')}) : res;
// res[0]: string value: stringValu
// res[1]: string2 value: stringValue
```

Good luck!